# Using the URLconf defined in crm1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django

hi im new to django and i am wondering why django is saying "Using the URLconf defined in crm1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, about, didn't match any of these."
urls file:

```
from django.urls import path

from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Home page')

def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse('contact page')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),
    path('about/',contact),
]
```

im following a tutorial on youtube and this is all the guy told me to write so far-

thankyouuu

Answer (score 0):

Which page are you requesting between 'home' and 'contact '?